# pandas create data frame, floats are objects, how to convert?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file:

```
sample    value1    value2
A    0.1212    0.2354
B    0.23493    1.3442
```

i import it:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fo:
    notes = next(fo)
    headers,*raw_data = [row.strip('\r\n').split('\t') for row in fo] # get column headers and data
    names = [row[0] for row in raw_data] # extract first row (variables)
    data= np.array([row[1:] for row in raw_data],dtype=float) # get rid of first row
```

if i then convert it:

`s = pd.DataFrame(data,index=names,columns=headers[1:])`

the data is recognized as floats. I could get the sample names back as column by s=s.reset_index().

if i do

`s = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=headers)`

the floats are objects and i cannot perform standard calculations.

How would you make the data frame ? Is it better to import the data as dict ?

BTW i am using python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your data file directly into data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', index_col='sample')
```

Which will give you:

```
         value1  value2
sample                 
A       0.12120  0.2354
B       0.23493  1.3442

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Then, you can do your computations.

Comment: What is the difference between importing my sample names as index and not ? I could use e.g df.groupby(by=df.index) or df.groupby(by=df.sample), respectively

Comment: That's just to automatically make the sample column as index. I just thought maybe that's what you want. But of course, you can choose not to depending on your use case.

Comment: Got it. If i import with `index_col=None`, i cannot do math. If i try to substract df.value1 from df.value2 i get an error: unorderable types: int() > str()
If i use `index_col='sample'` everything works fine.

Comment: Oh, i see. Nice to know that ;)

Comment: Oh no! now it is working regardles of how i import it (with None or 'sample'). I restarted my kernel. Something was messed up.

Answer (score 0):

To parse such a file, one should use pandas [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) function.

Below is a minimal example showing the use of [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) with parameter `delim_whitespace` set to `True`

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO  # Python2 or
from io import StringIO  # Python3

data = \
"""sample    value1    value2
A    0.1212    0.2354
B    0.23493    1.3442"""

# Creation of the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Python 3.3 does not have StringIO. It is called io. I did something like:
`df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',index_col=False, header=1, delim_whitespace=True)`